# Taylor diagram from existing Correlation and Standard Dev values

Tags: r

Is it possible to create a Taylor diagram from already calculated correlation and standard deviation values?

I am doing model evaluation, and I have already the correlation and standard deviations values.I understand that there is already a package **plotrix** where by giving the observation and the modeled values, the diagram is created. However for the type of work that I am doing, it is easier to start by giving already the correlation and standard deviation values.

Is there any way I can do this in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason it shouldn't be possible, but the authors didn't seem to allow for that when they wrote the function. The function is a bit long and complex, but the part that does the calculation is at the top. It is possible to swap out that code and replace it to allow for the passing of summary statistics. Now, keep in mind what i'm about to do is a hack and i've only tested it with versions 3.5-5 of plotrix. Other version may not work.

Here will will create a new function `taylor.diagram2` that takes all the code from `taylor.diagram` but adds in an extra `if` statement to check for a list of summarized data as the first argument

```
taylor.diagram2<-taylor.diagram
bl<-as.list(body(taylor.diagram))
cond<-list(
    as.name("if"), 
    quote(is.list(ref) & missing(model)),               #condition
    quote({R<-ref$R; sd.r<-ref$sd.r; sd.f<-ref$sd.f}),  #if true 
    as.call(c(as.symbol("{"), bl[3:8])))                #else
bl<-c(bl[1:2], as.call(cond), bl[9:length(bl)])         #splice in new code
body(taylor.diagram2)<-as.call(bl)                      #update function
```

Now we can test the function. First, we'll do things the standard way

```
#test data
aref<-rnorm(30,sd=2)
amodel1<-aref+rnorm(30)/2

#standard behavior function
taylor.diagram2(aref,amodel1, main="Standard Behavior"))

#summarized data
xx<-list(
    R=cor(aref, amodel1, use = "pairwise"),
    sd.r=sd(aref),
    sd.f=sd(amodel1)
)

#modified behavior
taylor.diagram2(xx, main="Modified Behavior")
```

So the new `taylor.diagram2` function can do both. If you pass it two vectors, it will do the standard behavior. If you pass it a list with the names `R`, `sd.r`, and `sd.f`, then it will do the same plot but with the values you passed in. Also, the `model` parameter must be empty for the modified version to work. That means if you want to set any additional parameter, you must use named parameters rather than positional arguments.

[image: taylor plot comparison]